# php empty row in a text record

Tags: php

I have a little problem with a record in a database.

I'm using php to retrieve data and when I take my record (description) I want: if there is some text with some space beetween row of my text I want to print the empty row.

example of my record:
Some text

Other text

I want to print the space between text of my record.

Comment: Stackoverflow works best if you provide an example of your code and explain where you are stuck. This really isn't the place to ask people how to build something from the ground up, although some might help you with it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not complete, please provide some code next time.

But I think you search for the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function which replace \n by the 
 HTML tag.

```
echo nl2br($row['description']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<?php
 echo "Some text";
?>
 &nbsp;<?php echo "Other Text";
?>
```